# Separating keywords from a line of text in batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, string

I'm admittedly new to using batch commands so i'm not sure if this is at all possible, if it isn't please let me know. Recently I made a simple batch command to list the directories of all files ending in .exe and out putting it into a text file i'm calling testpaths.txt

`dir C:\*.exe /s /b >> testpaths.txt`

This command works as intended and lists the entire directory like this

```
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

What I am looking to do is to write a script searching this document and separating for lack of a better term the part of the string that says *.exe so it looks like

```
notepad.exe
```

I am totally lost as to where or how I could even accomplish this as I am brand new to this. Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what you ask. You want to remove the rest so that only filename.exe remain  (as in remove the rest of the path) ?

Comment: Which software you are using for the search of the document and to extract the result

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I extract the filename from a list of files?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
dir C:\*.exe /s /b >> testpaths.txt
rem read the file one line at a time
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`type testpaths.txt`) do (
  rem extract the filename
  echo %%~nxi
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.